# Join table two column as 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

May I know how to join two columns table into as 1 column?

For example:

**Edited**

`first_table`

```html
id | folder | category id | status
1    Peter      5            0
2    John       6            1
3    Shawn      7            0
```

`second_table`

```html
id | filename| category id
1    123.sql     9
2    you.png    12
3    it.pdf     11
```

I want expected result like below, column **folder** and **filename** become store in 1 column and
column name as **folder_filename** :

`First table join Second table`

```html
id | folder_filename| category id | status
1    Peter               5            0
2    John                6            1
3    Shawn               7            0
4    123.sql             9
5    you.png             12
6    it.pdf              11
```

I tried below this sql, but not sure how to modify make it work.

```html
SELECT * FROM first_table INNER JOIN second_table
```

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
select f.id, f.folder, f.category_id
from first_table f
union all
select s.id, s.folder, s.category_id
from second_table s;
```

EDIT:

If you actually want to change the ids, then:

```
select row_number() over (order by which, id) as id, folder, category_id
from ((select f.id, f.folder, f.category_id, 1 as which
       from first_table f
      ) union all
      (select s.id, s.folder, s.category_id, 2
       from second_table s
      )
     ) fs

 ) fs
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff. If possible I added 1 more column in first table to union join?